# Unable to call DCRoundSwitch UIControlEventTouchUpInside event

Tags: objective-c, ios, custom-controls, uiswitch

I have used DCRoundSwitch to create custom switch,The problem is i'm unable to call UIControlEventTouchUpInside event,but only UIControlEventValueChanged event is getting called.

following is code i written in viewdidload:

```
self.swtchDailyReminder.on = YES;
self.swtchDailyReminder.onTintColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:47.0/255.0 green:160.0/255.0
blue:158.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
[self.swtchDailyReminder addTarget:self action:@selector(switchDailyReminderToggled:)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` message is sent by `DCRoundSwitch`'s `touchesEnded` method. So this method needs to be invoked in order for your switch to receive the message to trigger your action. This is not happening because `touchesCancelled` is being sent by the `UIGestureRecognizer`s - they automatically cancel touches to other views when they recognize their gesture. If you turn this behaviour off when the `UIGestureRecognizer`s are created and attached to the switch (in `DCRoundSwitch`'s setup method) using their `cancelsTouchesInView` property, that will allow touchesEnded to send it's `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` message to your switch, so that your action can be triggered.

Hope this helps.

// Note: If your target action is going to run some animations, you'll need to make some further changes to `DCRoundSwitch` to prevent it blocking your animations. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585923/uiview-animation-not-working-when-used-with-dcroundswitch/14064309#14064309) for more details