# UIView animation not working when used with DCRoundSwitch

Tags: objective-c, ios, custom-controls, uiswitch

I have done following code for animation inside a selector method of custom UISwitch DCRoundSwitch.

```
if ([[[App.remindersArray objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:3]isEqualToString:@"YES"]){

    [firstReminderOnOffButton setSelected:YES];
    [swtchDailyReminder setOn:YES];

    imgviewDailyReminder.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"nDailyReminder_On_1.png"];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.35];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animateFadingIn)];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
     imgviewDailyReminderAnimation.alpha = 1.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
else
{

    [firstReminderOnOffButton setSelected:NO];
    [swtchDailyReminder setOn:NO];

    imgviewDailyReminder.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"xDailyReminder_OFF.png"];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.35];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animateFadingIn)];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    imgviewDailyReminderAnimation.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

 }
```

The problem is animation is working properly when above code is called from normal UISwitch,but not working when called from DCRoundSwitch.

Also tried to resolve by using UIView block animation....but still facing the problem.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in `DCRoundSwitch's` animation block. No `CATransaction` is created in the completion block of `setOn:animated:ignoreControlEvents:` resulting in `[UIView animateWithDuration...]` methods not working properly when called in response to the switch's value being changed.

To solve the problem, just change:

```
if (previousOn != on && !ignoreControlEvents)
[self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

To:

```
if (previousOn != on && !ignoreControlEvents)
{
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setDisableActions:NO];
[self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[CATransaction commit];
}
```

That should do it

Answer (score 0):

i have used this below code. which works correctly.

Please follow up this thread

https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCRoundSwitch/issues/12

U can just go to the Class which is using this DCRoundSwitch , on that class's dealloc method put this line.

```
 - (void)dealloc
 {
      [self.MyDCRoundSwitch removeTarget:nil
                         action:NULL
                         forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
      [super dealloc];
 }
```